# Getting error "could not identify an equality operator for type json" with insert on conflict

Tags: postgresql, insert-update

When doing a bulk upload into a table that has a json column, I am getting the error "could not identify an equality operator for type json".  The json column is not part of any comparison (as far as I can tell), so I am mystified as to why I am getting the error.

Looking at the data being inserted, this everything appears correct.

The table is:

```
create table foo (
    c0  serial not null,
    c1  int4 not null,
    c2  timestamp not null,
    c3  timestamp not null,
    c4  bool not null
    c5  char(1) not null default 'I',
    c6  json not null default '[]'::json,

    constraint foo_pkey primary key (c0)
);

create unique index foo_idx on foo using btree (c1, c2);
```

And the python code using psycopg2 is:

```
def upsert_foo(cursor, data):
    sql = """
        INSERT INTO foo
            (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
        VALUES
            (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
        ON CONFLICT (c1, c2)
        DO UPDATE SET
            c3 = %s,
            c4 = %s,
            c5 = %s,
            c6 = %s;
        """

    execute_batch(cursor, sql, data)
```

The full error is:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: the update part should reference the `excluded` record, e.g. `set c3 = excluded.c3, c4 = excluded.c4`

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes there is, and your questions probably leads to the answer.

```SQL
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_foo_recmod
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW)
    EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_global_recmod();
```

I suspect the WHEN clause is the problem.

Comment: The ***WHEN*** clause in the trigger was the problem.  Thanks a bunch for jogging my memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the trigger on the table that had a when clause.  This failed because the table has a json column, which cannot be compared.  By removing the when clause from the trigger, the problem went away.